# How to make CKEditors modal dialogs modal to the window, not the frame

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, ckeditor

when having an frame-based interface, CKEditors modal dialogs only block the frame the editors has been loaded in. Is there a way to make dialogs modal to the the whole window?

André

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor dialogs are rendered in the DOM of the outer frame, not the inner. As such, rendering a model should 'block' the whole window.

Note, however, this is not a true 'blocking' action, such as **alert**, but rather a div overlay that is absolutely positioned over the entire window. It doesn't technically *block* the window below, but merely prevents access to the UI underneath.